# clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials - in CSOM returns 401 unauthorized thru IIS

Tags: client-object-model, csom, windows-authentication

I am trying to access SharePoint site using CSOM with Windows Authentication. It works if I run it in Visual Studio on a server. However, it returns a 401 unauthorized when I run the site through IIS on a server.

I have the followings set in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />

<identity impersonate="true" />
```

I have the followings ENABLED in IIS:

> "ASP.NET Impersonation" = ENABLED
>
> "Windows Authentication = "ENABLED"

I am not sure what I am missing here.  I have tried many different ways but no lucks yet.

Here is my code snippet:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(spUri))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; 
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web site = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(site);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
}
```

Comment: You are seeing the infamous "double-hop" issue. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx

Comment: @DerekGusoff: your link is dead.

Comment: sorry, it was live in 2015.

Answer (score -2):

Following code will work for sure.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://siteURL/")) 
{
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web site = context.Web;

   context.Load(site);

   context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Well yes, but it will not help in using windows authentication based on the logged in user