# How can I connect SQL DB to SharePoint List without Business Data Connectivity

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, database-connection

I have a table in a sql database that I'd like to use to populate (and regularly update) a List in SharePoint. I'm the manager for the site with this List, but not the installation (which includes hundreds of other sites). I'm a developer and have access to Visual Studio 2013 with Business Intelligence added in, so I was planning to setup an SSIS package, but can't figure out the connection without buying a product from CData.

I've tried SSIS SharePoint Online List Adapters from CodePlex, but the project won't build for me. Same issue with https://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/. I was hopeful with those, so maybe just need a better walk-through.

I **can** connect MS Access to the List using `External Data > Import or Link to a SharePoint List`, so I assume that this should be possible through code elsewhere, I just don't know how. I can also connect to the SQL database through Access, but don't want to have to run code in Access on a regular basis if I could just schedule an SSIS package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the open source list source en destination in the past, but when I search, they don't seem to be compatible with newer SQL Server versions. If you're comfortable coding, you could write your own destination connector based on the source code, but that seems like a lot of work. Maybe a simple executable and a scheduled task would do?

Otherwise I don't think there are a lot of options.

Comment: I am comfortable coding, and am looking into the REST Api for SharePoint, but am running into Credentialing issues and lacking examples.

Comment: CSOM and C# might be a better approach. Are you building an SSIS component or an executable?

Comment: I was hoping to just use a Data Flow Task in SSIS, but am open to using a Script Task, or just writing a console app.

Comment: This should get you started: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/create-update-delete-a-list-using-client-object-model-cso/

Comment: And to authenticate: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/clientcontext-credentials-credentialcache-defaultnetworkcredentials-in-csom